# different forms of equation of a parabola

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

**Question:**

> Find the equation of the parabola whose focus is $(1, -1)$ and whose
>   vertex is $(2, 1)$.

**My answer:** $$\left(x-1\right)^2+\left(y+1\right)^{2\ }=\frac{\left(2y\ +x\ -9\right)^2}{5}$$

**Answer key:**

$$\left(2x\ -\ y\ -3\right)^{2\ }=-20\left(x+2y\ -4\right)$$

**Discussion:**

It might initially appear that the two equations are different; however, **they are identical.**

My solution was to find the equation of the directrix. The idea was to find the distance between a variable point — $(x,y)$ — on the parabola from the directrix and the focus. The distances must be equal.

The interesting part is that the solution given in the answer key takes the following form:

$$(\text{axis})^2 = -20(\text{line passing through the vertex and perpendicular to the axis})$$

Is the above form always true? If the above form has a geometrical meaning, what quantity does the $-20$ indicate?

---

**Graphs:**

[image]

Comment: It is just the form obtained by turning the axes. Compare it with $Y^2=4AX$.